# How to delete CELLS and shift to right in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, startswith

So I have a below table

```
      P         Q          R      
| -------- | --------| --------
| Performan| Dispite | Cammmr
| Dispo    | camera  | battery
| Perfumo  | Displu  | Cammmmt
| Disper   | camera  | battery
| Dispite  | camera  | battery
```

so I want  the above table to appear like below :

```
|     P    |     Q    |     R   |    S
| -------- | -------- | --------
| Performan| Dispite  | Cammmr  | blank
| blank    | Dispo    | camera  | battery
| Perfumo  | Displu   | Cammmmt | blank
| blank    | Disper   | camera  | battery
| blank    | Dispite  | camera  | battery
```

so basically I wan to CUT values in column "P" which starts with "Dis" and then replace them by "blank" and then paste them in the adjacent column shifting thier values to right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

1. adds S column (value is 'blank')
2. make condition (starting with 'Dis' in P column) -> variable `cond`,
3. filters rows and shift and concatenate and so on.

```
df['S'] = 'blank'
cond = df['P'].str.startswith('Dis')
out = pd.concat([df[~cond], df[cond].shift(axis=1)]).fillna('blank').sort_index()
```

out:

```
           P        Q        R        S
0  Performan  Dispite   Cammmr    blank
1      blank    Dispo   camera  battery
2    Perfumo   Displu  Cammmmt    blank
3      blank   Disper   camera  battery
4      blank  Dispite   camera  battery
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'P': ['Performan', 'Dispo', 'Perfumo', 'Disper', 'Dispite'], 
         'Q': ['Dispite', 'camera', 'Displu', 'camera', 'camera'], 
         'R': ['Cammmr', 'battery', 'Cammmmt', 'battery', 'battery']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas shift with a condition(where column P has cells that starts with "Dis")

```
df['S'] = 'blank'
df[df['P'].str.startswith('Dis')] = df[df['P'].str.startswith('Dis')].shift(axis=1, fill_value='blank')
```

end result

| P | Q | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Performan | Dispite | Cammmr | None |
| None | Dispo | camera | battery |
| Perfumo | Displu | Cammmmt | None |
| None | Disper | camera | battery |
| None | Dispite | camera | battery |

Answer (score 0):

```
# For your case you can do the following:
# Add extra Column
df["S"] = "" 

# Filter rows with dis
dis_indices = df['P'].str.startswith("Dis")

# shift the rows
shifted_df = df.loc[dis_indices].shift(1, axis=1) 

# replace the rows
df[dis_indices] = shifted_df[dis_indices] 

# replace nan values
df.fillna("")
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to fill strings with `"blank"`, rather than an empty string`""`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).